# Invalid characters in Firebase Auth uid?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I want to combine multiple Firebase Auth `uid`s in a single string. So I need to know which characters can't possibly be in a `uid`. That way I can use one of them as a delimiter.

I've looked throughout Firebase's documentation and can't seem to find the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase User ID Allowed Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732330/firebase-user-id-allowed-characters)

Comment: It's in the getting started guide [Structure Your Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data) and says *If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation any string between 1 and 128 characters is allowed.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users (see: Table 1. Properties supported by the create user operation)

**Take care:** While the `uid` can be any string, the realtime database can't use any string. So if you want to use the `uid` to create a document you must obey those rules `Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`

Answer (score 0):

The default randomly-generated Firebase Authentication `uid`s are 28-character alphanumeric strings with no special characters.

---

Further research brought me to an answer from [Firebase User ID Allowed Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46909568/2754146) which suggests a pattern of:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]{27}[0-9]$
```

This matches the `uid`s I have across a couple of Firebase projects, so seems to be correct.

> From my experience, the latest version of Firebase follows the `^[0-9a-zA-Z]{27}[0-9]$` pattern.
>
> I don't know why there's always a digit at the end, but that seems to be consistent.